# Python time format with three-digit hour

Tags: python, datetime, date-format

How can I parse the time `004:32:55` into a datetime object? This:

```
datetime.strptime("004:32:55", "%H:%M:%S")
```

doesn't work becaush `%H` expects two digits. Any way to add the third digit?

Comment: So what's the background here? Is it possible that the hour part will contain more than 24 hours? I.e. days represented as hours?

Comment: @LukasGraf Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chose a more pragmatic approach in the end and converted the time stamp to seconds:

```
hours = (0 if time_string.split(":")[0] == "000" else int(time_string.split(":")[0].lstrip("0")) * 3600)
mins = (0 if time_string.split(":")[1] == "00" else int(time_string.split(":")[1].lstrip("0")) * 60)
secs = (0 if time_string.split(":")[2] == "00" else int(time_string.split(":")[2].lstrip("0")))

return hours + mins + secs
```

Converting back to hours, minutes, and seconds is easy with `datetime.timedelta(seconds=123)`.

**EDIT:**

A better solution (thanks to Ben):

```
hours = int(time_string.split(":")[0]) * 3600
mins  = int(time_string.split(":")[1]) * 60
secs  = int(time_string.split(":")[2])

return hours + mins + secs
```

Comment: Surely you don't need that first check on each line? `"000"` and `"00"` will both `int` to `0`...

Comment: @Ben True but lstrip removes all leading zeros so you'd end up with `int('')`, which throws an error.

Comment: But you don't need to `lstrip` at all do you? `int("01") == 1` ? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Ben Ah, actually, what I was thinking was that numbers with a leading zero are taken as octal values. Thus, e.g. `int(022)` is actually `18`. However, now I realized the code is `int`-ing a string, in which case it correctly removes the leading zero and converts `int("022")` to `22`. :-) Thanks for pointing this out, I'll amend the solution.

Comment: Yes, to make `int` think you meant octal you'd have to pass a second argument of `8` to `int`: `int("022", 8) == 18`. :)

Comment: `reduce(lambda total, new: total*60 + int(new), time_string.split(":"), 0)`

Answer (score 2):

Three options :

```
s = "004:32:55"


from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime(s[1:], "%H:%M:%S") # from second 0 to the end


datetime.strptime(s, "0%H:%M:%S") # add 0 in formatting

from dateutil import parser # use dateutil 

parser.parse(s)
```

There are 24 hours in a day so you can divide and get the modulus to figure out how many days and hours are in the time, then subtract the days, this needs some tweaking will get you started.

```
s = "04:32:55"

s = s.split(":",1)

hours, days = divmod(int(s[0]),24)

new_time = "{}:{}".format(hours,s[1])

past = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=days)
final = "{} {}".format(past.date().isoformat(),new_time)

print datetime.strptime(final,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: The first two approaches won't work since the hours could go beyond 24 hours, say 120 hours. How does the dateutil parser handle three digit hours?

Answer (score -1):

This solve my problem.
str(i).zfill(3)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).